# How to detect data changes in tableView JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

How to detect data changes(not only adding/removing but also changing properties of objects) in tableView populated by ObservableList which contains objects with such properties:

```
public class Car{
private SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private SimpleStringProperty brand = new SimpleStringProperty();
private SimpleStringProperty engine = new SimpleStringProperty();
private SimpleBooleanProperty navi = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
private SimpleBooleanProperty available = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
private SimpleDoubleProperty liters = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
private SimpleIntegerProperty power = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

(...)
}
```

In Controller class this is how i bound them together:

```
class MainController
{

@FXML
public void initialize()
{

    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, Integer>("id"));
    engineColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, String>("engine"));
    brandColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, String>("brand"));
    naviColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, Boolean>("navi"));
    availableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, Boolean>("available"));
    powerColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, Integer>("power"));
    fuelColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, Double>("liters"));
    carModel.getObservableList().add(new Car(213,"FIAT","1.9 JTD",true,true,32.4,132));
    tableView.setItems(carModel.getObservableList());
 }
```

I'm trying to add to initialize method listener for observableList but unfortunatelly it only detects adding and deleting objects from list. I want listener to update tableView whenever any property from object will be changed

```
carModel.getObservableList().addListener((Change<? extends Car> c) -> {
         while (c.next()) {
             if (c.wasAdded()) {
                 System.out.println("Added:");
                 c.getAddedSubList().forEach(System.out::println);
                 System.out.println();
             }
             if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                 System.out.println("Removed:");
                 c.getRemoved().forEach(System.out::println);
                 System.out.println();
             }
             if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                 System.out.println("Updated:");
                 carModel.getObservableList().subList(c.getFrom(), c.getTo()).forEach(System.out::println);
                 System.out.println();
             }
         }
      });
```

I found such sollution on forum which as I said detects only adding/removing objects

Comment: [Construct the list the right way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-) or manually add/remove listeners - your choice... Or simply execute the desired code when you modify the properties... (`TableColumn.onEditCommit` could be used for editable columns...)

Comment: "I want listener to update tableView whenever any property from object will be changed". Assuming you have defined the methods in `Car` following the [usual pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107), the table view will automatically update when the properties change. There is no need to use an extractor or define additional listeners, [`PropertyValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) already does the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only a fact of changed one of properties the simplest way will be to concat all properties into one `ObservableValue`.

In your `Car` class have this method:

```
ObservableValue changeProperty() {
    return Bindings.concat(id, brand, engine, navi, available, liters, power);
}
```

on client side you just listen it:

```
    car.changeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            // one of property was changed, do something
        }
    })
```

The same way if you need to detect the changes among all cars:

```
ObservableValue changeProperty() {
    return Bindings.concat(car1.changeProperty(), car2.changeProperty(), carN.changeProperty());
}
```